# C program: Calculating Interest

Tags: c

**Intent** : This program asks a user for The amount that is currently in their bank account, the APR and the number of years. The output is the starting and ending of the amount that shows an accumulative interest of the years specified by the user.

**Question:** I'm trying to find a way to correctly add the interest, as of right now for a specified amount of years all i'm doing is multiplying the (current amount in bank account * interest rate * years) I know this is wrong and I think I need a loop for the accumulating interest rate from one year to the next and that's where I need help.Thanks and here is my current code below...

---

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float getPV()
{
    float d;
    float start;
    printf("Start: ");
    scanf("%f", &start);
    d = start;
    return d;
}


void getIR(float *a)
{
    printf("Rate: ");
    scanf("%f",a);
}

void getNP(int *years)
{
    printf("NumPeriods: ");
    scanf("%d", years);
}
float interest(float a,float b,float c)
{
    float x;

    x = a*b*c;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    float pv,ir,fv,Total;
    int np;

    pv = getPV();        //Amount in account

    getIR( &ir );        // APR

    getNP( &np );        // Number of years

    fv = interest(pv,ir,np);
    Total=fv + pv;
    printf("Starting:   %.2f\n", pv);
    printf("  Ending:   %.2f\n", Total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **PLEASE** edit your question to make it readable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Do you want simple or compound interest? Also reduce the font of the question to a more manageable size. preferably default size.

Comment: Not sure what help you need. Yes, you need a loop unless you're going to dust off the [`pow()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) function. Any of literally a million places online can give you the formula for compounding interest, which you then translate to either a loop or that function call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
float interest(float a,float b,float c)
{
    return a * pow(1.0f + b, c);
}
```

Assuming `b` is a number like 0.05 to mean 5% a year, and `c` is a number of years (which doesn't have to be an integer).

Comment: The name of this function doesn't reflect what it actually computes. This is indeed the correct formula for computing *future value*, but not *interest*.  The interest can be calculated by subtracting `1.0` from the right-term prior to the final multiplication. Right idea, however.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the OP's function signature. I agree that choosing appropriate names is very important. _There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things._  ^_^